# Error when installing "teaspoon" with pip: "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install the package 'teaspoon' using pip and I keep getting this error message:

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/deas/Documents/Python/PH practice/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/deas/Documents/Python/PH practice/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/deas/Documents/Python/PH practice/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/zq/x_rnw3kx2hb8c65kwlyr1xvm0000gp/T/pip-build-env-fdu04mfy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/zq/x_rnw3kx2hb8c65kwlyr1xvm0000gp/T/pip-build-env-fdu04mfy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/zq/x_rnw3kx2hb8c65kwlyr1xvm0000gp/T/pip-build-env-fdu04mfy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 45, in <module>
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['xcrun', '--show-sdk-path']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have wheel installed.

What's the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: `missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun` looks a bit iffy

Comment: @SiHa What do you mean by that?

Comment: It means you're missing the [system dependencies](https://github.com/TeaspoonTDA/teaspoon#installation).

Comment: @wim I'm sorry, I'm so new to all this, how do I remedy that issue?

Comment: Do you have the developer tools for mac installed?  seems like your missing xcode stuff.

Comment: @LhasaDad Probably not, is that a package that I can install with pip?

Comment: https://ma.ttias.be/mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun/

Should help you install xcrun

Comment: no, its a mac thing.  you need to get it from apple

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ for info

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed the XCode commandline tools. You can do that via commandline with this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

See also [teaspoon's installation instructions](https://github.com/TeaspoonTDA/teaspoon#installation):

> To install this package, both boost and CMake must be installed as system dependencies. For boost see for [unix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) and [windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). For mac, you can run `brew install boost` if using homebrew as a package manager. For CMake see [here](https://cmake.org/install/).